# Version of the application in Google Play does not match the manifest

Tags: android, google-play, version, publishing

Placing the application in Google Play, I saw that the required version set to "1.6 or later", but in the manifest worth 4.0.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Comment: it takes 2-3 hours for changes to get reflected on Google play and sometime more than 5 hours so wait for that time and if you still get the same problem check with your Google play developer console account

Comment: I got this proble two days ago. What I need to check in my developer console account?

Comment: your apk version and other details. have you uploaded right apk file?

Comment: Can I change version which displaying manually?

Comment: no you cant change that manually. your apk should be compatible with that version.

Comment: Yes, I think it's right version. If you have complex answer, please write it like Answer, not the comment. It will be grateful.